# Help with significant figures unit conversion...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I am having trouble remembering the trick to convert from square metres etc. to square millimetres.

Say I have $2\cdot{10}^{-3}m^2$ and I want to get it into millimetres.

I vaguely remember converting part of it back to millimetres and then involving the power somehow but I can't figure it out. I have done it thousands of times before, don't know why I can't do it all of a sudden. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A square meter is a square 1 meter on a side.  A meter is 1000 millimeters.  So that square meter is how many millimeters by how many millimeters?

Comment: $1m=1000mm$; so $1m^2=1000\times 1000mm^2=10^6mm^2$. So ..

Comment: Yes I can understand the basic math there but I know there is a neat physics trick when dealing significant figures and changing units. I remember converting one part to millimetres, then introducing some brackets and adding or subtracting the powers. Something along those lines

Comment: $10^{-3}m^2 = 10^{-3}(1m)^2 = 10^{-3}(10^3mm)^2 = 10^{-3}(10^3)^2mm^2 = 10^{-3}10^6mm^2 = 10^3mm^2$

Comment: Yes I can follow that one. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reliable way to convert units is to write (e.g.)
$$
1 m = 1000mm
$$
Therefore
$$
2\cdot{10}^{-3}m^2 = 2\cdot{10}^{-3}  (1000mm)^2
\\ = 2\cdot{10}^{-3} \times 1000^2 mm^2
\\ = 2\cdot{10}^{3} mm^2
$$

Comment: Yes that's the one I was looking for. Just replacing the units first. I know all the others are right as well so I appreciate the responses, it's just this one is easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

How about this?  Since $1$m $=1000$mm, multiply by $\left(\dfrac{1000\text{mm}}{1\text{m}}\right)^2$.

Comment: I get $1000000mm^2/1m^2$?

Comment: Correct.  Since the numerator and denominator are equal, you're just multiplying by $1$ and not changing the value.